# Sync error while trying to build project in IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

Getting the following sync error while trying to build my first helloWorld program in IntelliJ.

I've installed IntelliJ for the first time on my computer running Windows 10.

```
    Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\nikhils\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init5.gradle' (C:\Users\nikhils\.gradle\caches\6.6.1\scripts\2xaig2b083uxqwleg0fdntova).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60
```

Answer (score 8):

Change project and Gradle JDK to the supported version (8—15). Current Gradle release versions do not support Java 16. You would need Gradle 7 if you want to use Java 16.

The easiest way would be to create a new project with Java 11.

Also note that full Java 16 support will be available starting from IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 release (current release version is 2020.3.3).

See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/ if you want to give it a try.