# Attempting To Run Kotlin Project In IntelliJ Idea But Getting Bug Error

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, ide

**My Previous Question + More**

---

I am trying to start learning Kotlin, and I have installed IntelliJ Idea from JetBrains, I really like the layout of the IDE, and so I don't really want to change it.

Whenever I try to run the program, I get the following error:

```
Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init1.gradle' (C:\Users\Jacob\.gradle\caches\6.6.1\scripts\9x7j38tmeo1ohlyu8452ntfdm).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60
```

I know it's not the code, and since I am not very familiar with IntelliJ Idea or Kotlin, I have no idea where to start looking for the error or where to fix it...

---

Someone said that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079327/how-to-fix-unsupported-class-file-major-version-60-in-intellij) question's answers were the solution, but I looked their, tried what it shows, but still found now solution for my situation... When I follow what they say, I get the same error.

**Someone please help!!!**

Comment: Do you use a JDK 16 in `File | Project Structure | Project | Project SDK` or in `Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle`?  Please try updating the [Gradle to 7.0](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html) or use a lower JDK to see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you! Your comment as well as [Maxim Kochetkov's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14711501/maxim-kochetkov) answer helped me fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created instruction:

- Install JDK (for example [Oracle JDK 14](https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/14.0.2+12/205943a0976c4ed48cb16f1043c5c647/jdk-14.0.2_windows-x64_bin.exe))
- Open project folder with [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/kochetkov-ma/pump-samples/blob/master/kotlin-get-started/build.gradle) and [`settings.gradle`](https://github.com/kochetkov-ma/pump-samples/blob/master/kotlin-get-started/settings.gradle) in Idea
- Add JDK to project: press `F4` on left `Project Tool` -> `SDk` -> `Add` -> `Apply`

  [image: SDk]
- Set new SDK to project: press `F4` on left `Project Tool` -> `Project` -> `Project SDK` -> `Set new SDK` -> `OK`

  [image: Set SDK for Project]
- Set new SDK to `Gradle Build Tool`: press `Ctrl + Alt + S` -> Find `gradle` in search -> Go to `Gradle JVM` -> Set new SDK -> `OK`

  [image: Set SDK for Gradle]
- Create new directory `src/main/kotlin/main.kt` with code

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val jdk = System.getProperty("java.version")
    println("Using JDK: $jdk")
}
```

- Go to `main.kt` in Editor and press `Ctrl + Shift + F10` and you must see your JDK version in console like: `Using JDK: 14.0.2`

Take a look [sample project](https://github.com/kochetkov-ma/pump-samples/tree/master/kotlin-get-started)

Comment: Thank you for these instructions... but it doesn't solve my problem... I think it may be in the run configuration, what do you have for that?

Comment: Okay, nevermind... it actually _does_ solve my problem... as well as the comment that [@floatingcat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2331527/floating-cat) posted in my question. I had just forgot to change the Gradle one after I had installed one not v16... for some reason that doesn't work with my computer...