# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

Configuration :
Java : 16 
Gradle : 7.2 
Jacoco : 0.8.4

When I upgraded my project from openJDK8 to openJDk16 I see the following issues :

**"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60"**

And also the below issue : 

**java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting sun/security/ec/SunEC$1.
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_035b120.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:93)
at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:244**

Comment: The error actually means that the class was compiled with higher java version (16) but run with lower one (8).
Check gradle JVM version by the command: `./gradlew -version` and make sure that gradle uses `16` (check `JAVA_HOME` in environment variables)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "unsupported class file major version 60" in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079327/how-to-fix-unsupported-class-file-major-version-60-in-intellij)

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem when upgrading my project to use JDK17 ( i.e., Unsupported class file major version 61 ).

The solution was to upgrade jacoco maven plugin to version 0.8.8 in my pom

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.8</version>
            ...
```

this github thread is also related:
https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2835

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and fix it by chaining Gradle JVM settings in my preferred IDE which is IntelliJ (should be possible with others too):

1. In the Settings/Preferences dialog, go to Build, Execution,
   Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle.
2. Under the Gradle section, change the Gradle JVM option.

If you are using Intellij you can see more on this topic [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-jvm-selection.html#jvm_settings)