# Errors compiling gradlew commands in flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, visual-studio-code, gradlew

I'm new to flutter, using VS Code on Windows, and was following a tutorial that told me to run these two commands in the terminal (PowerShell) for making a firebase app.

```
cd android
./gradlew signingReport
```

I tried to do so many times, and then ran flutter doctor to ensure I was doing it right. It came up normal, and then I opened up Android Studio and decided to run the signingReport command again, this time in an old Kotlin app, and it worked fine. The error I keep getting in VS Code, both through the command prompt and PowerShell (not that it makes a difference) is

````
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\mossp\Downloads\Programming\flutter_windows_2.10.2-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.5.0\android\build.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\mossp\Downloads\Programming\flutter_windows_2.10.2-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.5.0\android\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 62

  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 62
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:251)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:189)        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:169)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:125)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClassNullable(AsmReferenceResolver.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClass(AsmReferenceResolver.java:44)        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveNonArrayType(AsmReferenceResolver.java:79)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveType(AsmReferenceResolver.java:70) 
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.MemberSignatureParser.createMethodNode(MemberSignatureParser.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode$2.get(DecompiledClassNode.java:234)        
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode$2.get(DecompiledClassNode.java:231)        
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.createMethodNode(DecompiledClassNode.java:242)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.lazyInitMembers(DecompiledClassNode.java:199)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.getDeclaredMethods(DecompiledClassNode.java:122)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getMethods(ClassNode.java:912)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.tryFindPossibleMethod(ClassNode.java:1280)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(StaticImportVisitor.java:252)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:142)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:121)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(StaticImportVisitor.java:89)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructor(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:128)        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1099)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:54)       
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.visitClass(StaticImportVisitor.java:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$14.call(CompilationUnit.java:708)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1084)   
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:640)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:618)      
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:595)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:401)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.access$300(GroovyClassLoader.java:89)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:341)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:338)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.ConcurrentCommonCache.getAndPut(ConcurrentCommonCache.java:147)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:336)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:139)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:95)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler$2.run(BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.java:51)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CompileToCrossBuildCacheAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:190)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$CompileToCrossBuildCacheAction.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:170)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:211)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler$ProgressReportingInitializer.execute(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:194)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$Initializer.initialize(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:100)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess$1.run(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:86)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:215)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:205)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.open(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:139)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:78)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:42)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:95)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:68)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:126)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.compile(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:116)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.CrossBuildInMemoryCachingScriptClassCache.getOrCompile(CrossBuildInMemoryCachingScriptClassCache.java:50)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildScopeInMemoryCachingScriptClassCompiler.compile(BuildScopeInMemoryCachingScriptClassCompiler.java:50)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptCompilerFactory$ScriptCompilerImpl.compile(DefaultScriptCompilerFactory.java:49)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:110)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)     
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)     
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:248)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:275)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:247)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)       
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)       
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:248)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:308)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:178)  
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:308)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:289)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:247)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:710)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:145)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:36)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:64)        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:46) 
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:57)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareProjects(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:228)   
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:165)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)     
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)      
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:72)      
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)      
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:178)  
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)       
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:87)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)    
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)    
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)     
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)       
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)   
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s```
````

How can I find a possible solution?

Comment: Please check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079327/how-can-i-fix-unsupported-class-file-major-version-60-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Thank you so much, it turns out that you just have to downgrade your jdk to an older version.