# BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63 IntelliJ Idea Error

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, semantic-analysis, java-19

Just started to learn Kotlin on IntelliJ Idea, immediately hit with this bug

Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\MrHi\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init22.gradle' (C:\Users\MrHi.gradle\caches\7.4.2\scripts\4be2wxazmlr4zgpqtfq0njegl).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

im using IntelliJ Idea with Java 19 and Oracle JDK 19.0.2

Comment: You should upgrade gradle to 7.6, which added support for Java 19

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix "unsupported class file major version 60" in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079327/how-can-i-fix-unsupported-class-file-major-version-60-in-intellij-idea)