# How to get my IntelliJ Education version to use a newer version of Gradle (8.4)

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform

I've searched all over the place to figure out how to get my IntelliJ Education version to use a newer version of Gradle (8.4) that can use JDK 21. DOes any one know how to change the IntelliJ so it will STOP trying to use the internal Gradle 7 which complains about the JDK 21 that I am using? EVerything else has no issue with JDK 21 and I do not want to set JAVA_HOME to another version of Java just because IntelliJ doen't like. it.

I am being forced to use Intellij due to some Kotlin source files.

repeatedly try to build a sample KT project and I keep getting this error. Don't know how to get IntelliJ to just use my 8.4 gradle. I remember seeing sometning about a tool window to link to my own gradle but now it is totally hidden from any views.

"Found Invalid Gradle JVM configuration
JDK 21.01 isn't compatible with Gradle 7.4
Please fix JAVA_HOME envirionmental variable. "

Comment: Possibly relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079327/how-can-i-fix-unsupported-class-file-major-version-60-in-intellij-idea?rq=2

Comment: Check IDEA's Gradle settings ("Distribution" option): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_version_install