# In flutter project android folder showing an error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'.
Process 'command 'D:\Flutter\test2\android/gradlew.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

**I have tryed to rebuild it but after it showing this**

> Task :gradle:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\Users\UMER\dev\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\app_plugin_loader.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 65

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix "unsupported class file major version 60" in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079327/how-can-i-fix-unsupported-class-file-major-version-60-in-intellij-idea)