# altbeacon library sample app Unsupported class file major version 61

Tags: java, android, beacon

I need to bolt beacon detection on to my existing app.
I have followed the android documentation for this.
I have downloaded the sample app from
https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference

I have installed Hedgehog Android IDE

When I build I receive error : Unsupported class file major version 61

Here are the gradle settings that come with the app:

```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> 
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 29
>     buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
> 
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "org.altbeacon.beaconreference"
>         minSdkVersion 21
>         targetSdkVersion 29
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     } }
> 
> dependencies {
>     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
>     //implementation project(':android-beacon-library:lib')
>     implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+' }
```

Q1:Can anyone please tell me where I should look for incompatible versions of java.

Q2:Is this the default generic library to use ? are there any others ? I have had no luck with Kbeacon.

I have been adding to this app over 10 years for my client but this latest requirement and all the difficulties I have encountered makes me feel like giving up and telling them to hand the job to a dedicated Android development house.

Many thanks in advance
Tony

Comment: Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079327/how-can-i-fix-unsupported-class-file-major-version-60-in-intellij-idea). You may need java 17 instead (refer to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout:~:text=Java%20SE%2017%20%3D%2061%20(0x3D%20hex))).

Answer (score 0):

Please use library version 2.19.5

Starting with library version 2.19.6, the library is compiled with JDK 17. You may also need to use JDK 17 for your app in order to use 2.19.6 or later.

Unfortunately, this upgrade was necessary for the library to allow targeting Android 14 and the latest Android Studio and Gradle build tools. See here for more info: https://developer.android.com/build/jdks

Comment: Sorry - I'm confused.
I want to use the latest version of the library as my main application has been pushed right through to Android 14.
But to get this java sample working - I would assume that if I have installed Hedgehog then I would have the latest JDK. 
Which component is out of date, where do I go to change it, and what should I set it to ?
Many thanks
Tony

Comment: Interestingly - I can compile library org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.20.3 in my main application project.
I copied MonitoringActivity, RangingActivity, BeaconReferenceApplication, in to my main application. I changed the manifest to reflect MonitoryingActivity as the launcher. I copied the permissions.
it compiles and runs but says "No Beacons Detected" and "didDetermineStateForRecgion called with state: OUTSIDE(0).
The kotlin version works fine and detects beacons and reports their id and rssi etc

Comment: I also added in all the layouts.

Comment: If you are seeing the "Unsupported class file major minor" error, you need to make configure Android Studio to use a Java 17 installation on your computer.   See [here](https://developer.android.com/build/jdks#jdk-android-studio) The java reference app has not yet been converted to use Android 14 which is likely why you do not see the error there.   If you aren't detecting with the app, make sure that permissions are granted at runtime.  You need code to request them from the user, but you can manually go to Settings -> Apps -> Your app -> Permissions to grant them.